# sed replaces '=' sign when only dot present in negated set

Tags: bash, sed

The file `hi` contains single line: `bali=hi`.

Would like to to replace hi with bi if hi is not preceded with `.` (dot).

Expected `sed  -n "s/[^.]hi/bi/p" /tmp/hi` to produce `bali=bi`.
However the output is `balibi`

How to achieve the desired replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a capture group and back-reference:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^.])hi/\1bi/g' /tmp/hi
```

Here we are capturing line start or a non-dot character in group #1 which is being used in replacement as back-reference i.e. `\1`.

**Examples:**

```
sed -E 's/(^|[^.])hi/\1bi/g' <<< 'bali=hi'
bali=bi

sed -E 's/(^|[^.])hi/\1bi/g' <<< 'bali.hi'
bali.hi
```

Comment: `-E` is for extended regex. Usually `-r` is mentioned in manuals for gnu sed but `-E` behaves same and is more portable.